# Understanding rubygems 'require' in sudo vs rvmsudo

Tags: ruby, rvm, upstart, rvmsudo

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.4 TLS

I wrote a simple shell script in `/home/abdo/sample_serv.sh` that executes a Ruby file:

```
#!/bin/bash
/home/abdo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby /home/abdo/sample_serv.rb
```

and `/home/abdo/sample_serv.rb` containing the code below:

```
puts $:

require 'sinatra'

set :port, 8084

get '/' do
  %{ <html><body>Hello from Abdo</body></html> }
end
```

Executing `rvmsudo ./home/abdo/sample_serv.sh` works just fine but I would like to get `sudo ./home/abdo/sample_serv.sh` to work by passing the necessary environment variables because I am having issues with `upstart`.

The issue arises in my `/etc/init/foo.conf`

```
description "webserver test"

start on runlevel [23]
stop on shutdown

pre-start script
  exec >> /var/log/unicorn_test.log 2>&1
  echo starting
end script

script
  exec >> /var/log/unicorn_test.log 2>&1

  /bin/bash /home/abdo/.rvm/bin/rvmsudo /home/abdo/sample_serv.sh
  echo started
end script
```

When the line `/bin/bash /home/abdo/.rvm/bin/rvmsudo /home/abdo/sample_serv.sh` is reached, I get

```
/home/abdo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in 
`require': cannot load such file -- sinatra (LoadError)
```

I was able to get the same `ruby -v` as that of my user but it looks like the `GEM_PATH` (even if I set it inside the upstart config file), is not helping.

Basically, if I can understand how (and where -- `gem env` is not helping since `gem` is not a command when I do `sudo`) `rubygems` looks for a file being required, I should be able to move forward.

Answer (score 1):

When you run under `sudo` you run in a different environment, where `gem` is not installed, the `$PATH` is different, so things may not run smoothly.

You may want to try [this](https://rvm.io/integration/sudo):

> **Changing sudo's strict defaults**
>
> There are 3 things needed to mitigate this situation if you encounter
>   it:
>
> - the user that is invoking sudo must have `export rvmsudo_secure_path=0` set on his shell environment (think .bashrc,
>     .bash_profile or .zshrc)
> - comment out `Defaults secure_path=...` on /etc/sudoers
> - add `Defaults env_keep +="rvm_bin_path GEM_HOME IRBRC MY_RUBY_HOME rvm_path rvm_prefix rvm_version GEM_PATH rvmsudo_secure_path
>     RUBY_VERSION rvm_ruby_string rvm_delete_flag"` to `/etc/sudoer`s in
>     rare cases it is required to add more variables - they should be
>     reported by first run of `rvmsudo`.
>
> After these changes, you should be able to use `rvmsudo` preserving
>   the same password/no-password directives as "normal" sudo calls.

**Edit**

If you don't want to change the defaults, you can try to synchronize the values of the environment values stated above (`rvm_bin_path GEM_HOME IRBRC MY_RUBY_HOME rvm_path rvm_prefix rvm_version GEM_PATH rvmsudo_secure_path RUBY_VERSION rvm_ruby_string rvm_delete_flag`) to your `root` user.

If that doesn't work, you can try installing `rvm` as `root`, and using that environment (instead of `/home/abdo/.rvm/bin/rvm`) to run your code.

Comment: This is a good start... I do not wish to change sudo's strict defaults though. Thank you for your response :-)

Comment: Added some alternatives

Comment: Thanks so much for the information above. +1 for now, will accept when I confirm :-)

Comment: Delayed this part of the project as I have prioritized others. Should get to it in a week or so. I will be trying this answer as soon as we get there :-)